# Postman pm.response.to.have.header not working as expected

Tags: automated-tests, postman

- Using Postman version v6.1.3 See
- https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/test_examples

***PART 1***

Postman's test examples include this test to see if a header is present:

```
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type");
});
```

My response headers contain this:

```
Content-Type →application/json
```

I expect the test above to PASS, but it FAILS.  Why?
It says:

```
FAIL  Content-Type is present | AssertionError: expected response to not have header with key 'Content-Type'
```

Further, since the above test FAILS, then I would expect this negative test to succeed, but it FAILS too:

```
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type");
});
```

It says:

```
FAIL  Content-Type is present | AssertionError: expected response to not have header with key 'Content-Type'
```

Note that this is the EXACT SAME error message as above.  They both say "expected response to not have" which seems wrong to me.

***PART 2***

Just to make the whole experience more confusing, testing for the ***key and value*** string works.  Am I misunderstanding of "have.header"?

```
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.header("Content-Type →application/json");
});
```

It returns:

```
PASS  Content-Type is present
```

And yet again, the negative test for this ***ALSO PASSSES!***

```
pm.test("Content-Type is present", function () {
    pm.response.to.not.have.header("Content-Type →application/json");
});
```

It returns:

```
PASS  Content-Type is present
```

***PART 3***

***Help?!***

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems to be related to this bug:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3690

"pm.response.to.not.be causes later assertions to work backwards."

Answer (score 0):

You probably got this working by now but anyways here is what worked for me:

```
pm.test("Content Type is present", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response).to.have.header("Content-Type");
})
```